# How to select for something that begins with a string but doesn't end with a different string in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery, exploring its syntax a bit.

My page has elements like this:

```
<area id="SA" ... />
<area id="AF" ... />
<area id="EU" ... />
<area id="NA" ... />
```

I am trying to show and hide `div` sections based on click events off the `area` tags, which have matching ending ID's, coded like this:

```
<div id="div_SA" ... />
<div id="div_AF" ... />
<div id="div_EU" ... />
<div id="div_NA" ... />
```

So, to show the exact match, but hide all the `div` sections which have id's that start with "div_" but don't otherwise match, without hiding every other `div` on the page, I tried this:

```
    var q = 'div[id="div_' + event.target.id + '"]';
    var r = 'div[id^="div_"],div:not[id$=' + event.target.id + '"]';
    $(q).show();
    $(r).hide();
```

`$(r).hide();` is not working. What am I doing wrong? (I know I could assign CSS classes and get at them with class names, but I'm still curious about how to construct a query that will work this way.)

Comment: For evaluating q, I would simply use q = '#div_' + this.id;

Comment: Well there's clearly more than one way to do it. I checked the one I used, which is working, and, thank you for the demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** See below for the syntax fix as mentioned in your post,

```
   var q = '#div_' + this.id;
   var r = 'div[id^="div_"]:not("#div_' + this.id + '")';

   $(r).hide();
   $(q).show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YuSJt/2/)

Please check the alternate solution below,

For evaluating q, I would simply use

```
var q = $('#div_' + this.id);
```

And for r,

```
var r = $('div[id^="div_"]').not(q);

r.hide();
q.show();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YuSJt/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Make things as easy and simple as possible, since you are new at jQuery, you should get the habit of using `on()`. Not `click()`, that is outdated, and simply just refers to the on method.

```
$('area').on('click', function() {
    var id = "#div_" + $(this).attr('id'),  // comma allows you to make multiple variables
        divs = $('div').hide() // puts all the divs in a variable and automatically hides them all

    // filter through all the divs, and selects the one with the id,
    // of the area that was clicked, and shows it
    divs.filter(id).show();
});​
```

Hope this could help you for now. If not, please let me know.

Comment: Excuse me, can you explain why click() is outdated? Or the advantages of using the on()? Please. PD: Sorry for the offtopic

Comment: `.click()` has as long as i remember always been outdated. It's there to make things a bit easier. What `.click()`, `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.deligate()` do is that they all refere to the `.on()` method ( `.unbind()' refers to `.off()`.) So instead of always refering to the `.on()` method, it's best practise to just use the `.on()` method.

examples:
_you bind the .on() to the element you want to click_
`$('div').click(fn)`= `$('div').on('click', fn)`

Comment: _if you are dynamically adding to the dom, bind .on() to something that is already in the dom, the parent element, and listen for it:_
`$('div').live('click',fn)`= `$(document).on('click','div', fn)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `not` css pseudo selector uses parenthesis not brackets. Also you have an unmatched quotation mark towards the end before the last bracket.

```
var r = 'div[id^="div_"],div:not(#' + event.target.id + ')';
```

Also, your code can be simplified by changing it to:

```
var q = '#' + event.target.id;
var r = 'div[id^="div_"]:not(#' + event.target.id + ')';

$(q).show();
$(r).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('area').click(function() {
    var areaID = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div[id^="div_"]').hide();
    $('div[id^="div_' + areaID + '"]').show();
});​
```

Comment: Hides the whole page, which is made of `div`s

Answer (score 0):

```
//start by selecing all of the DIV elements that have an ID attribute that starts with "div_",
//and hide all of them,
//then filter that list down to only the element(s) that have an ID that ends with the id of the `event.target` element
//and show that/those element(s) 
$('div[id^="div_"]').hide().filter('#div_' + event.target.id).show();
```

Comment: This is going to hide all div and then show the selected one.. which is going to give you a flicker effect.

Comment: @SKS - It will not give any flickering effect as it happens within micro seconds.

Comment: @SKS ShankarSangoli got to it before me, but this is minor and most likely won't cause any flickering: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/aGG9R/

Comment: ok.. minor or not.. why would you want to hide all and show selected. If that 'minor' is acceptable.. why do you need a filter.. just use $('#div_' + event.target.id).show();

Comment: @SKS I used the filter since the set of elements in which the one I want is already selected, so I can use `.filter()` knowing that only a small number of elements will be looked-through rather than the whole DOM. This is an extremely minor performance increase.

Comment: We are looking at an ID selector here.. not class selector. I am not sure if $('#div_' + event.target.id) is faster or looping through $(div[id^="div_"]).

Comment: @SKS When an ID is used to select an element, all the nodes are looked through until the correct node is found, then the search stops since it's assumed that IDs are unique. This still means that you could iterate over many elements before finding the correct one (although selecting by ID is going to be fast anyway). Using filter, we look for an ID within a known small set of elements.

Comment: mm yea.. true. It is always resource vs speed. but I guess looping over a smaller subset is better in this case.

Comment: @SKS Honestly I don't know the answer of what's faster, but those are my thoughts, I'll have to run a performance test to find-out.

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple

```
// cache divs, no need to search them again
var divs=$('div[id^="div_"]');
$('area').click(function(){
        divs.hide().eq( $(this).index() ).show();                
});
```